# Count of each unique element in a list

Tags: python, count

Say I have a list of countries

```
l = ['India', 'China', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA', 'India', 'USA']
```

and then I have a list of unique countries

```
ul = ['India', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA']
```

I want to have a count of each unique country in the list in ascending order. So output should be as follows:

```
Japan 1
China 2
India 2
USA   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort depending on the `ul` list, you can use list comprehension like:

```
l = ['India', 'China', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA', 'India', 'USA']
ul = ['India', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA']
result = sorted([(x, l.count(x)) for x in ul], key=lambda y: y[1])
for elem in result:
    print '{} {}'.format(elem[0], elem[1])
```

output:

```
Japan 1
India 2
China 2
USA 2
```

And if you want to sort by alphabet after sorting by count, you can change `result` to the following:

```
result = sorted(sorted([(x, l.count(x)) for x in ul]), key=lambda y: y[1])
```

output:

```
Japan 1
China 2
India 2
USA 2
```

Comment: The list comprehension using `count` is significantly slower than the `Counter` approach - order n^2 compared to order n just to count. See this answer for profiling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909767/2337736

Comment: This approach just incase he has a pre-defined list of items (as mentioned in the example) that he wants to search for, not all of the items

Comment: Even then I think you'd want to profile something like `ul_set = frozenset(ul); counts = Counter(country for country in countries if country in ul_set)` - you really want to avoid running `count` multiple times on the same list. I mean, it's fine for short lists, but you might as well use the faster tools.

Answer (score 9):

You can use Counter from collections:

```
from collections import Counter

l = ["India", "China", "China", "Japan", "USA", "India", "USA"]

new_vals = Counter(l).most_common()
new_vals = new_vals[::-1] #this sorts the list in ascending order

for a, b in new_vals:
    print a, b
```

Comment: Is the output of `Counter(l).items()` guaranteed to return a a list sorted by count? I think you need to use `most_common()`

Comment: Agreed. The `Counter` docs give this recipe for n least common: `c.most_common()[:-n-1:-1]` - which simplifies to the usual `[::-1]` if n is equal to the total number of items.

Comment: @Ajax1234 What if I run this on my data and I get the error - TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: Did you use exactly the data that is hard coded in this example, i.e "l" ?

Comment: That exception indicates that your list contains at least one dict - counters require that the elements you're counting be hashable, and dicts are not.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper I guess you are correct. What is the solution to this?

Comment: Could you post your data with the dictionary that you are using?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a `Counter` you can count yourself (you already know the unique elements because you have `ul`) using a dictionary:

```
l = ['India', 'China', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA', 'India', 'USA'] 
ul = ['India', 'China', 'Japan', 'USA']

cnts = dict.fromkeys(ul, 0)  # initialize with 0

# count them
for item in l:
    cnts[item] += 1

# print them in ascending order
for name, cnt in sorted(cnts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]):  # sort by the count in ascending order
    print(name, cnt)   
    # or in case you need the correct formatting (right padding for the name):
    # print('{:<5}'.format(name), cnt)
```

which prints:

```
Japan 1
China 2
India 2
USA   2
```